# What is the simplest way to upload a file in Python from a web browser?

Tags: python

I have searched.  Everything I can find is a huge file.  It can't be that hard.  C# has a SaveAs, PHP uses the $_FILES array.  Python was all over the place.  Cgi, httprequest, urllib, urllib2, httplib2, how to do it in Django, Pylons, Flask, etc.  Java was complex as well.

All I want to know, please, is what is the most super-basic way to upload a file from a webpage.

Python 2.7 or Python 3 made no difference in my search.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:  For clarification, I mean like any webpage that has the "Upload" button.  Could be here, Craiglist, anything.  All I really want to do is upload an image file and save it on the server.

EDIT:  Part of the problem is there are so many libraries and everyone saying to use x.

EDIT:  The server could be Apache or IIS.

Comment: where does the file exist? do you have a url for the file? where do you want the file to go? How is the server expecting this file?

Comment: What do you mean by "upload from a webpage", could you give an example? Like, when you upload an image from your computer to StackOverflow?

Comment: @tobias_k I think so.  I haven't uploaded an image in a long time.  I clarified in my question.

Comment: Why I'd get a downvote, I do not know.

Comment: I think you are asking about uploading a file from a web browser *to* your Python program, right? If so, then your question needs clarification like which web server framework do you use?

Comment: @Krumelur Yes.  I want a user to go go my webpage, click upload file, it goes to my Python page.  My Python page saves it.

Comment: But how is it set up? Are you creating a full-blown webapp (e.g. Django)? Or are you just using SimpleHTTPServer for some hack?

Comment: @Krumelur One webpage.  One Python page.  That's it.

Comment: Then I suggest that you start with `SimpleHTTPServer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What is the simplest way to upload a file in Python from a web browser?"

I don't think there is a simple way, because this question doesn't make much sense.  There are at least three ways to interpret this question :

1. If you want to upload a file with Python acting as a web-browser onto a remote server, one of the easiest ways is to use the `requests` library.
2. If you want to upload a file from a web browser, which Python is controlling, onto a remote server, then you could use the `selenium` library to drive a firefox browser.
3. If you want to upload a file with a web browser onto a remote server that is running Python, there is no "simple" way to do it. Python doesn't have the "it just runs" integration with apache like PHP does.  While there are some open source projects for getting Python to work in Apache, most people opt to run their Python code either as it's own daemon or through some sort of WSGI server or proxy.

The simpler ways to handle #3-

- The easiest way to do web stuff is `web.py`.  Its very simple and limited.
- If you're willing to do a bit more work, there are micro-frameworks like `flask` and `bottle`
- There's another tier of minimalist frameworks, which contain `pyramid`, `tornado`, `twisted`, `cherrypy` and more.  they tend to be very powerful, but don't make any decisions for you.  Someone posted this link the other day comparing a few - http://codecondo.com/14-minimal-web-frameworks-for-python/
- Finally you have full-fledged frameworks like `django` , `turbogears`, `web2py`, which make a lot of decisions for you.

Generally speaking, each framework deals with the GET/POST data from the request differently.  While the `cgi` package is often wrapped, there's no real consensus on which library should be used to handle file uploads.  A lot of frameworks seem to integrate `webob` to handle that stuff in a WSGI stack.

/updated/

Some simple ways to get python up and running:

- most frameworks will offer a lightweight daemon for testing or low-load conditions.  you can just run it as-is off the commandline , and it will bind to a high port (like 8080)
- you can have Apache/IIS proxy requests to the higher port if you don't want to hit it directly
- you can use something like `gunicorn`, `uwsgi`, `eventlet`, or probably 12+ other libraries to run the uwsgi environment.

personally, I do this

- nginx on port 80
- development - proxypass to the script's test-daemon, running on higher port ( for Pyramid/Pylons that is paster, for web.py it's just the commandline )
- production - run via uwsgi

Comment: Actually, it is fairly easy to do file upload over CGI, just like e.g. PHP. But it is usually not worth the effort, given that Python's builtin servers are usually good enough until you want to switch to FastCGI etc.

Comment: Yeah. ONe *could* run a script via cgi, but it is almost always a nightmare to configure and the environments vary so much from box to box. You spend 20minute on your script, then 4hours configuring a web-server that risks putting everything else into downtime while you work things out.  It's generally way way way faster and not nearly as dangerous to avoid the cgi/fcgi route and just use builtin server or WSGI server.  The builtin servers almost all speak WSGI now, and are preferable to CGI.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco The more I look at using Python on the web, the more I want to stay away.  I know many use it but it seems so ill suited for the web.  Other stuff I like it.  Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: Python is perfect for the web. You can build way more robust sites faster with it than PHP or other options.  The big difference between vs PHP, is that you're typically building 'web applications' with Python/Ruby , while PHP is often used to build a 'web page'.  With PHP, you're running an isolated script that relies on a black-box of  Apache/FCGI setting everything up for you.  With Python, you usually have control of the entire stack.  If you have a very small project, Python is often overkill.  If you have a medium-to-large one, it's pretty much the best option out there -- by far.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco It may be but it is the most unintuitive I have seen.  I really want to use it though.

Comment: Try doing something simple in Flask or Django.  They're both very intuitive and powerful.  I prefer Pyramid, but it has a steeper learning curve.